# AXValidationManager taking 200 milliseconds of startup time

Tags: ios

On iOS 7, I'm seeing AXValidationManager take 200 milliseconds of time right after my app starts, which causes stutter in all my animations. How do I get rid of this Apple framework call?

Profile trace from instruments:

https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1271832/2145363/11f87984-93a2-11e3-8699-cdd58a50b30e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a result of frameworks like AdMob that prefetch ads and put them into a hidden UIWebView. For some reason a good chunk of time is spent on the main thread. Seems like a bad way to do it. They ought to be doing a request in the background and saving the html off and then only creating a web view when the ad is about to be displayed.